# named can not find a certain domain

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, bind, centos6

I have setup `named` in `chroot` and it has been working for some days. Now it does not find a certain domain's IP:

```
# dig arstechnica.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.30.rc1.el6_6.1 <<>> arstechnica.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Other domains are normally discovered:

```
# dig serverfault.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.30.rc1.el6_6.1 <<>> serverfault.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 27016
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 2

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;serverfault.com.       IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
serverfault.com.    98  IN  A   198.252.206.140

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
serverfault.com.    172598  IN  NS  cf-dns02.serverfault.com.
serverfault.com.    172598  IN  NS  cf-dns01.serverfault.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
cf-dns02.serverfault.com. 172598 IN A   173.245.59.4
cf-dns01.serverfault.com. 172598 IN A   173.245.58.53

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Mon Dec 22 11:06:10 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 127
```

`named.conf`:

```
# cat /var/named/chroot/var/named/chroot/etc/named.conf 

options {
    listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; };
    listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
    directory   "/var/named";
    dump-file   "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
    statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
    memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
    allow-query     { localhost; };
    recursion yes;

    dnssec-enable yes;
    dnssec-validation yes;
    dnssec-lookaside auto;

    /* Path to ISC DLV key */
    bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";

    managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";
};

logging {
    channel default_debug {
        file "data/named.run";
        severity dynamic;
    };
};

zone "." IN {
    type hint;
    file "named.ca";
};

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";
```

All files in that directory:

```
# ll /var/named/chroot/var/named/chroot/etc/
total 16
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   118 Jul 21  2011 localtime
drwxr-x---. 2 root named 4096 Dec 12 02:25 named
-rw-r-----. 1 root named 1008 Dec 17 20:02 named.conf
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root     0 Dec 22 10:35 named.iscdlv.key
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root     0 Dec 22 10:35 named.rfc1912.zones
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root     0 Dec 22 10:35 named.root.key
drwxr-x---. 3 root named 4096 Dec 17 19:15 pki
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root     0 Dec 22 10:35 rndc.key
```

What am I missing?

---

`+trace` added:

```
# dig arstechnica.com +trace

; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.30.rc1.el6_6.1 <<>> arstechnica.com +trace
;; global options: +cmd
.           516879  IN  NS  m.root-servers.net.
.           516879  IN  NS  h.root-servers.net.
.           516879  IN  NS  g.root-servers.net.
.           516879  IN  NS  j.root-servers.net.
.           516879  IN  NS  a.root-servers.net.
.           516879  IN  NS  l.root-servers.net.
.           516879  IN  NS  e.root-servers.net.
.           516879  IN  NS  f.root-servers.net.
.           516879  IN  NS  k.root-servers.net.
.           516879  IN  NS  b.root-servers.net.
.           516879  IN  NS  d.root-servers.net.
.           516879  IN  NS  i.root-servers.net.
.           516879  IN  NS  c.root-servers.net.
;; Received 228 bytes from 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1) in 577 ms

com.            172800  IN  NS  m.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  l.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  k.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  j.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  i.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  h.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  g.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  f.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  e.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  d.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  c.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  b.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  a.gtld-servers.net.
;; Received 493 bytes from 192.58.128.30#53(192.58.128.30) in 2270 ms

arstechnica.com.    172800  IN  NS  ns1.servercentral.net.
arstechnica.com.    172800  IN  NS  ns2.servercentral.net.
;; Received 118 bytes from 192.12.94.30#53(192.12.94.30) in 579 ms

;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

dig to github:

```
# dig github.com +trace

; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.30.rc1.el6_6.1 <<>> github.com +trace
;; global options: +cmd
.           516495  IN  NS  k.root-servers.net.
.           516495  IN  NS  e.root-servers.net.
.           516495  IN  NS  f.root-servers.net.
.           516495  IN  NS  b.root-servers.net.
.           516495  IN  NS  g.root-servers.net.
.           516495  IN  NS  d.root-servers.net.
.           516495  IN  NS  m.root-servers.net.
.           516495  IN  NS  c.root-servers.net.
.           516495  IN  NS  j.root-servers.net.
.           516495  IN  NS  h.root-servers.net.
.           516495  IN  NS  a.root-servers.net.
.           516495  IN  NS  i.root-servers.net.
.           516495  IN  NS  l.root-servers.net.
;; Received 508 bytes from 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1) in 5 ms

com.            172800  IN  NS  a.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  b.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  c.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  d.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  e.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  f.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  g.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  h.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  i.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  j.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  k.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  l.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  m.gtld-servers.net.
;; Received 488 bytes from 193.0.14.129#53(193.0.14.129) in 74 ms

github.com.     172800  IN  NS  ns1.p16.dynect.net.
github.com.     172800  IN  NS  ns3.p16.dynect.net.
github.com.     172800  IN  NS  ns2.p16.dynect.net.
github.com.     172800  IN  NS  ns4.p16.dynect.net.
;; Received 178 bytes from 192.31.80.30#53(192.31.80.30) in 323 ms

github.com.     30  IN  A   192.30.252.131
github.com.     86400   IN  NS  ns4.p16.dynect.net.
github.com.     86400   IN  NS  ns2.p16.dynect.net.
github.com.     86400   IN  NS  ns1.p16.dynect.net.
github.com.     86400   IN  NS  ns3.p16.dynect.net.
;; Received 130 bytes from 204.13.251.16#53(204.13.251.16) in 10 ms
```

Comment: In your first example: `dig arstechcnica.com` there is a typo in the domain name.

Comment: it seems that you've missed the .com part of the arstechnica.com domain. Please try: dig arstechnica.com and come back to us with the results :)

Comment: @pvod Yes. It just times out.

Comment: Can you add ```+trace``` to the end of your dig command and post the output.

Comment: @Dayvo Updated.

Comment: Can you just attempt to do the same dig to github.com as well please, with a trace.

Comment: @Dayvo Updated.

Comment: Both of those sites have IP addresses starting ```192.``` I assume your server has an IP address of that as well and your netmask is set too wide. Does this server have an IP address starting with ```192.```?

Comment: @Dayvo From `ifconfig`: inet addr:64.x.x.x  Bcast:64.255.255.255  Mask:255.0.0.0 The mask is calculated by the system.

Comment: Hmm, that is strange. I see the output from ```+trace``` isn't complete, did it timeout?

Comment: @Dayvo No, it did not time out. That is all the output.

Comment: Yeah, that's wrong. It can reach `192` addresses fine. But: `ns1.servercentral.net. IN A 64.202.100.113` -- your netmask is way to wide! Nice catch @Dayvo

Comment: Ah, that'll be it @faker. Surprising how many times this crops up. To confirm @Clodoaldo you'll need to change your Netmask to cover only the assigned IP range, you should be able to get this from your host but it should be at least ```255.255.255.0```.

Comment: @Dayvo Narrowing the netmask fixes it. Now on to find out the correct netmask...

Comment: Great, I'll pop an answer in to help anybody else who searches for the same/similar issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The netmask set on the IP address which the server is using (`64.x.x.x`) was to `255.0.0.0`, this is to wide, meaning that requests for any domains which also start with the IP address `64.` were not being routed out of the server correctly.

The resolution to this issue was to lower the netmask used on the IP address on the local machine to be 255.255.255.0, meaning that any addresses starting `64.` will still be resolved externally to the machine.